# Add 'Page' above page numbers in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I am using my school's latex [cls file](http://www.timehaven.org/public/UAFTHESIS_LATEX_TUTORIAL.tgz). Unfortunately, since this package was last updated, we are now required to add the word 'Page' above the topmost page number on each page of the Table of Contents. This cls file includes the following bit of code, which puts 'Page' at the top of the first page, but not any subsequent pages (see attached)

```
\newcommand\chapteruaf{
\if@arabic\relax\else\if@chapterone\setcounter{page}{1}\else\relax\fi\fi
\@chapteronefalse
                    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{myheadings}%                                                                               
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapteruaf}
\def\@schapteruaf#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterheaduaf{#1}]%                                                                   
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterheaduaf{#1}%                                                                                 
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterheaduaf#1{%                                                                                                 
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \reset@font
    \normalsize \bfseries  #1\par                                                                                             
    \vspace{-18.3pt}\hspace{143mm} Page                                                                                       
    \nobreak
  }}
```

First page of the TOC:
[image]

second page of the TOC:
[image]

Any thoughts here? I have played with this a bit, and can't get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A table of contents is often less than 3 pages so you can simply insert the command into the toc file. With the package `afterpage` you do not have to know where the pagebreak will happen:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par\medskip}}
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage
\section{foo}bar\clearpage

\end{document}
```

For other lists, eg List of Figures, use

```
\addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
...
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par\medskip}}
```

and so on.

Comment: @Herbert I have a table of contents of 3 pages and so your suggestion just helped get the word page on the 2nd page of TOC and not on the 3rd page. Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: @ShraySharan: Add the line `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~...` again where the second page break appears in your document

Comment: @Herbert And what change should i make in the command if I want to add the word Page in the List of figures as well

Comment: `\addtocontents{lof}{...` the first argument is the file extension, in this case _ListOfFigures_. See my edited answer

Comment: @Herbert Thanks a lot... And with this my document is complete... I had another question... I just used the 2nd command out of the 2 commands that you mentioned and the word page was added in both toc and lof. Could you please explain what each of these 2 commands do in the document?

Comment: see http://texblog.net/help/latex/addcontentsline.html

Comment: here how to add title and chapter no?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `tocloft` package to customize the layout of the table of contents, list of figures, list of tables, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\hfill\normalsize\bfseries}
% On the same line
%\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill\llap{\bfseries Page}}
% On the next line
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill\null\\\null\hfill\textbf{Page}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{asdf}
\section{qwer}
\section{zxcv}
\end{document}
```

The commented out line should be used if you want the **Page** to appear on the same line as **Table of Contents** and the uncommented line should be used if you want it to be on the next line.

You can also add the dot leaders to sections (or chapters, if you're using chapters) with

```
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdotsep}
```

or

```
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
```

Comment: Hmm, when I \usepackage{tocloft}: ! LaTeX Error: Command \c@lofdepth already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual. I am guessing this comes down to something from the cls file...

Comment: per this thread: http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg16706.html, if \usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} is called, things work fine. Unfortunately, this solution seems to still only place 'Page' on the first page of the TOC, and nothing else. Also for some reason it is killing the pagebreak between the TOC and LOF and is altering the fonts and layout of the front matter significantly.

Comment: @mrdillon: Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you only wanted it at the top. Herbert's approach seems like a good approach. `tocloft` allows a fair bit of customization, so it doesn't surprise me that it changes the layout, but it gives you a uniform way to change the layout.

Comment: @mrdillon: You should be using the `subfig` package instead of the older `subfigure`. Then there's no need to use the `subfigure` option to `tocloft`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, as it turns out we go to the same school, and are dealing with the same `uafthesis` bugs! I've been fixing mine on github at http://github.com/jesusabdullah/uafthesis.

Fwiw, I read the handbook, and it says we only need "page" above the *first* page, from what I can tell.

Comment: From the 09/10 Handbook:
4.10 Table of Contents
The title block “Table of Contents” must appear at the upper margin of the first page and be centered. The title block is not repeated on any subsequent pages. Dotted leaders are preferred between headings and page numbers. **The word “Page” should be typed above the listing of the page numbers on each page of the Table of Contents.**