# "Page" heading on contents tables

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

Currently, this code generates pages that look something like:

```
  First thing.................i
  Second thing...............ii
1 First Big Chapter...........1
```

and so forth, which is fine *except* that I need the word "page" above the right-hand column:

```
                           Page
  First thing.................i
  Second thing...............ii
1 First Big Chapter...........1
```

I need this "Page" heading on the Table of Contents, List of Figures and List of Tables.

**UPDATE:**

After my previous attempts at adding `\hfill Page` into the \tableofcontents macro in [uafthesis.cls](https://github.com/jesusabdullah/uafthesis), I tried a new approach based on 
[this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8296/add-page-above-page-numbers-in-table-of-contents). It's pretty close, but there's one problem: The bibliography now has a "Page" header too! I've tried using the TeX \newif and friends to make it go away, but no dice.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, because there is none. »Page« is also inserted automatically into LoF and LoT by the class. So there is no need for supplements.

Comment: This is because I just added it.  I've been hammering at this problem all day.

Right now I'm at the point where I can get "Page" inserted into everything I want...but NOW it *also* inserts in the bibliography! /o\ I tried making that go away with some TeX \if action, but no dice. :(

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you added the lines 396-399 to the source of the class file. Delete them and try the approach shown below.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{uafthesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill Page\par}
  \addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill Page\par}
  \addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill Page\par}
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables

  \blinddocument\cite{key}

  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{Dummy figure}\label{tab:dummy}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
  \end{table}

  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{key} Bibliography Item
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

In case these lists spread over multiple pages, you will have to add the term »Page« anew as shown in [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8296/add-page-above-page-numbers-in-table-of-contents/8298#8298) to the mentioned question.

By the way, it is no good practise to edit a class file. You better redefine the critical parts in the preamble. Note that the [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only for creating the dummy document thus not part of the solution.

Comment: "By the way, it is no good practise to edit a class file."

Normally I would agree, but this is supposed to be the official class file for theses at my university. I'd rather the class file work as expected than have to throw a bunch of stuff into the preamble.

Comment: @Joshua: Must have missed that. Then you should put `\AtBeginDocument` into the class file. You may replace it with `\AtEndOfClass` (but seems not necessary). For details have a look at Section 4.6 in the document »[LaTeX2e for Class and Package Writers](http://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide)« (also know as class guide).

Answer (score 4):

I think my thesis requirements are worse, and I satisfied them all with [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) pagestyles and hooks. It's also entirely possible there are more elegant ways of getting this done. Suggestions welcome.

---

Page 1 of ToC: page number at bottom-center, like plain, with "Page" right justified above page number column:

[image]

```
\copypagestyle{toc-initial}{plain}
\renewcommand{\aftertoctitle}{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\onelineskip}\vspace{\onelineskip}
  \mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}
  \par\nobreak
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagestyle{toc}%
    \protect\thispagestyle{toc-initial}}%
}
```

Pages 2-M of ToC, where M is defined as the last page with chapter entries: page number at top-right, with "Page" right-justified above page number column, and "Chapter" left-justified above the chapter entries:

[image]

```
\makepagestyle{toc}
\makeoddhead{toc}{\chaptername}{}{%
  \enlargethispage{-3\onelineskip}\normalfont\thepage\par%
  \vspace{\onelineskip}Page}
\makeevenhead{toc}{\chaptername}{}{%
  \enlargethispage{-3\onelineskip}\normalfont\thepage\par%
  \vspace{\onelineskip}Page}
\makeoddfoot{toc}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{toc}{}{}{}
```

Pages M+1-N of ToC (i.e., pages with nothing but Appendix entries): page number at top-right, with "Page" right-justified above page number column, and "Appendix" left-justified above the appendix entries:

[image]

```
\makepagestyle{toc-app}
\makeoddhead{toc-app}{\appendixname}{}{%
  \normalfont\thepage\par%
  \vspace{\onelineskip}Page}
\makeevenhead{toc-app}{\appendixname}{}{%
  \normalfont\thepage\par%
  \vspace{\onelineskip}Page}
\makeoddfoot{toc-app}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{toc-app}{}{}{}
```

Page 1 of LoF, LoT, etc: page number at bottom-center, like plain, with "Page" right justified above page number column:

[image]

```
\copypagestyle{lot-initial}{plain}
\renewcommand{\lotheadstart}{\newpage \chapterheadstart}
\renewcommand{\afterlottitle}{%
  \let\numberline\oldnumberline
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\onelineskip}\vspace{\onelineskip}
  {\normalfont Table}\hfill{\normalfont Page}
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\onelineskip}
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\pagestyle{lot}\protect\thispagestyle{lot-initial}}
}
```

Pages 2-K of LoF, LoT, etc: page number at top-right, with "Page" right-justified above page number column, and "Table," "Figure," etc. left-justified above the appendix entries:

[image]

```
\makepagestyle{lot}
\makeoddhead{lot}{\tablename}{}{%
  \enlargethispage{-3\onelineskip}\normalfont\thepage\par\vspace{\onelineskip}Page}
\makeevenhead{lot}{\tablename}{}{%
  \enlargethispage{-3\onelineskip}\normalfont\thepage\par\vspace{\onelineskip}Page}
\makeoddfoot{lot}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{lot}{}{}{}
```

There's a bit more on my [development version](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/browser/trunk/ttuthesis.sty) (automagic `\checktocheaders`, `\fixtocheaders`, and a few other things to hide the pagestyle commands from my users), but the above is the core of it.