# Modifying Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to modify the Table of Contents by adding the words "CHAPTER NO", "CHAPTER NAME" and "PAGE NO" above the respective columns.

Presently my ToC looks like this...

```
            Acknowledgement     i
            Abstract            ii

1           Introduction        1
            1.1 Some heading    2

2           Similar way         4
```

I want it to look Like ...

```
Chapter No  Chapter Name    Page No

            Acknowledgement     i
            Abstract            ii

1           Introduction        1
            1.1 Some heading    2

2           Similar way         4
```

Any way I could go about accomplishing this? Also the same for List of Figures and List of Tables.

Comment: Related: [“Page” heading on contents tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16423/5764)

Comment: Which document class do you use? Have you made any changes to the default layout of the ToC? If so, please add the relevant info in your question. In any case, at least mention the document class used.

Comment: I used the extreport class
(http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extreport.cls)
I modified the toc to remove the dots
\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
No other changes to toc

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but adding a simple line can be done by:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\makebox[2cm][l]{Chapter No.}\makebox[6cm][l]{Chapter Name}\hfill\makebox[2cm][l]{Chapter page}}
```

Maybe the commands must be protected by `\protect`. OF course you must setup the correct widths of the `toc` entries.