# How do I add the words "chapter no., title, and page no." in between the title of the TOC and above the acknowledgement in the report class?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to change like this by the following images for TOC, LOF and LOT.

For TOC.

[image: I want to change like this]

For LOF.

[image: Same case for LOF]

and For LOT.

[image: and for LOT]

The codes.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of contents}} 
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill} 
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{19.5pt} 
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase{list of figures}}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill} 
\renewcommand{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitleskip}{19.5pt} 
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{\cftnodots} 

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase{list of tables}} 
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill} 
\renewcommand{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitleskip}{19.5pt} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftnodots} 

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\MakeUppercase{Abstract}}
\input{pages/abstract.tex}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{Acknowledgements}}
\input{pages/acknowledgements.tex}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\makebox[2cm][l]{Chapter No.\protect\makebox[10cm][l]{Title}\hfill\protect\makebox[2cm][l]{Page No.}}}
\newpage

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
\newpage

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I also tried this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53306/modifying-table-of-contents), but its not working properly like this images.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using,

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide an MWE, from `\documentclass,,,` to `\end{document}`, showing what you have tried. This is not a "do it for me" site but we can try and improve your code.