# Adding words figure and page to list of figures

Tags: floats, sectioning, front-matter, afterpage

This also applies to the table of contents and list of tables and is related to [Add 'Page' above page numbers in Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8296/add-page-above-page-numbers-in-table-of-contents), but when adding the words "Figure" and "Page" to the top of a List of Figures that spans more than one page, the additions are typset differently on the first page than on the second.

Here I use `\addtocontents{lof}{{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}\par}` following `\listoffigures` to make the addition to the first page, and `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}\par}}` between figure 2.8 and 2.9 to make the addition to the top of the second page.

I rather like how the first page appears, the spacing looks right. I cannot understand why the second page appears differently. I also understand that `\noindent`in the place of `~` preceding the word "Figure" in my code may be more appropriate. The question is why the different behavior? How can I do this so that the text appears the same on each page. Any thoughts? Have spent quite a lot of time on this but can't reach a solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{lof}{{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}\par}
\mainmatter
\chapter{one}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{one}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}\par}}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the line

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}\par}}
```

with

```
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{\protect\hbox to \linewidth%
                    {{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}}\par%
                    \protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
\makeatother
```

Note that, since you're using `afterpage`, you don't need to guess where to put these lines. You can put them just after

```
\addtocontents{lof}{{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}\par}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{lof}{{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}\par}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{\protect\hbox to \linewidth%
                    {{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}}\par%
                    \protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
\makeatother
\mainmatter
\chapter{one}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{one}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Works great, thank you so much! Out of curiosity, why is it that the first page behaves differently than the later pages?

Comment: @Geoarch In the first page, the list has not started yet. In the second page, everything you insert, you insert it inside the list. Also, a skip of 10pt is inserted just before the list begins. Try to write `\noindent{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}
\begin{enumerate} \item[] {~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}
\end{enumerate}` and you will see the same effect.

Comment: @Geoarch You're welcome. :-)