# List-of-Figures/Tables Header on each page issue

Tags: table-of-contents

I have used the solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306938/force-figures-page-header-to-appear-on-every-page-of-list-of-figures) to force the header onto every "list of figures" and "list of tables" page; however, it's creating a weird additional spacing for every page beyond the first and I am unsure what is causing it or how to resolve it. Without the linked solution there is no spacing issue.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: fancyhdr is known for changing the page geometry after the first page if \headheight is not large enough.

Comment: I ended up editing the output PDF to resolve the issue provided this occurred days before the submission deadline.